# How to show calendar month's previous days?

Tags: php, calendar

I'm trying to make a calendar that shows this month, and then fills in the remaining days on the end rows with the dates from the next and previous months.

I managed to make it show next months dates and the thing is the issue is that I need it to show previous months dates as well.

If someone manages to figure out the issues please add what the problem was as well how you managed to fix it, to help me in the future.

I will add a image of the calendar as well.

[image]

The script:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" class="view-calendar">
<tr>
<td valign="top" width="14.2857%">Mondag</td>
<td valign="top" width="14.2857%">Tuesday</td>
<td valign="top" width="14.2857%">Wednesday</td>
<td valign="top" width="14.2857%">Thursday</td>
<td valign="top" width="14.2857%">Friday</td>
<td valign="top" width="14.2857%">Saturday</td>
<td valign="top" width="14.2857%">Sunday</td>
</tr>

<?php
// Get current month dates
$days_count = date('t');
$current_day = date('d');
$week_day_first = date('N', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1, date('Y')));

// Get previous month dates

// Get next month dates
$next_start = strtotime(date("Y-m-00", strtotime("+1 month")));
$next_dates = array();

for ($w = 1 - $week_day_first + 1; $w <= $days_count; $w = $w + 7){
  echo '<tr>';
  $counter = 0;
    for ($d = $w; $d <= $w + 6; $d++){
      if($d < 10){
        $current_date = date("Y").date("m").'0'.$d;
      }else{
        $current_date = date("Y").date("m").$d;
      }
      echo '<td valign="top" width="14.2857%"'.(($d > 0 ? ($d > $days_count ? ' class="disabled"' : '') : ' class="disabled"')).(($counter > 4 ? ' class="week-day"' : '')).'>';
      if($d > 0){
        if($d > $days_count){
          for($in = 1; $in <= 1; $in++){
            echo array_push($next_dates, date('j', strtotime("+ $in day", $next_start)));
          }
        }else if($current_day == $d){
          echo '<div class="current-day"><span class="given-date">'.$d.'</span></div>';
        }else{
          echo '<span class="given-date">'.$d.'</span>';
        }
      }else{
        //Here comes previous dates
      }
      echo '</td>';
      $counter++;
    }
  echo '</tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: So is your question *"Please complete this section:* `// Get previous month dates`" ?

Comment: No the question is how can I manage to show the previous dates in the empty boxes, like in June, I want to show 30th and 31st may. @JeffPuckettII

Comment: OK, so you just want to fill in that row with the 30 and 31. That's much clearer thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you calculated `$week_day_first`, you can save your time calculated from the first day of the month into a variable.

```
$time_first_day_of_month = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1, date('Y'));
```

Then you can reuse that later to calculate the offset of days before the first of the month.

```
date('d', strtotime("$offset day",$time_first_day_of_month))
```

Putting it all together:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" class="view-calendar">
<tr>
<td valign="top" width="14.2857%">Mondag</td>
<td valign="top" width="14.2857%">Tuesday</td>
<td valign="top" width="14.2857%">Wednesday</td>
<td valign="top" width="14.2857%">Thursday</td>
<td valign="top" width="14.2857%">Friday</td>
<td valign="top" width="14.2857%">Saturday</td>
<td valign="top" width="14.2857%">Sunday</td>
</tr>

<?php
// Get current month dates
$days_count = date('t');

$current_day = date('d');

// save time of first day for later use
$time_first_day_of_month = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1, date('Y'));
$week_day_first = date('N', $time_first_day_of_month);

// Get next month dates
$next_start = strtotime(date("Y-m-00", strtotime("+1 month")));

$next_dates = array();

for ($w = 1 - $week_day_first + 1; $w <= $days_count; $w = $w + 7){
  echo '<tr>';
  $counter = 0;
    for ($d = $w; $d <= $w + 6; $d++){
      if($d < 10){
        $current_date = date("Y").date("m").'0'.$d;
      }else{
        $current_date = date("Y").date("m").$d;
      }
      echo '<td valign="top" width="14.2857%"'.(($d > 0 ? ($d > $days_count ? ' class="disabled"' : '') : ' class="disabled"')).(($counter > 4 ? ' class="week-day"' : '')).'>';
      if($d > 0){
        // next month's dates
        if($d > $days_count){
          for($in = 1; $in <= 1; $in++){
            echo array_push($next_dates, date('j', strtotime("+ $in day", $next_start)));
          }
        }
        // today
        else if($current_day == $d){
          echo '<div class="current-day"><span class="given-date">'.$d.'</span></div>';
        }
        // this month's dates
        else{
          echo '<span class="given-date">'.$d.'</span>';
        }
      }
      // last month's dates
      else{
        //Here comes previous dates
        $offset = $d - 1;
        echo '<span class="given-date">'.date('d', strtotime("$offset day",$time_first_day_of_month)).'</span>';
      }
      echo '</td>';
      $counter++;
    }
  echo '</tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```

Results in this output:

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" class="view-calendar">
<tr>
<td valign="top" width="14.2857%">Mondag</td>
<td valign="top" width="14.2857%">Tuesday</td>
<td valign="top" width="14.2857%">Wednesday</td>
<td valign="top" width="14.2857%">Thursday</td>
<td valign="top" width="14.2857%">Friday</td>
<td valign="top" width="14.2857%">Saturday</td>
<td valign="top" width="14.2857%">Sunday</td>
</tr>

<tr><td valign="top" width="14.2857%" class="disabled"><span class="given-date">30</span></td><td valign="top" width="14.2857%" class="disabled"><span class="given-date">31</span></td><td valign="top" width="14.2857%"><span class="given-date">1</span></td><td valign="top" width="14.2857%"><span class="given-date">2</span></td><td valign="top" width="14.2857%"><span class="given-date">3</span></td><td valign="top" width="14.2857%" class="week-day"><span class="given-date">4</span></td><td valign="top" width="14.2857%" class="week-day"><span class="given-date">5</span></td></tr><tr><td valign="top" width="14.2857%"><span class="given-date">6</span></td><td valign="top" width="14.2857%"><span class="given-date">7</span></td><td valign="top" width="14.2857%"><span class="given-date">8</span></td><td valign="top" width="14.2857%"><span class="given-date">9</span></td><td valign="top" width="14.2857%"><span class="given-date">10</span></td><td valign="top" width="14.2857%" class="week-day"><span class="given-date">11</span></td><td valign="top" width="14.2857%" class="week-day"><span class="given-date">12</span></td></tr><tr><td valign="top" width="14.2857%"><span class="given-date">13</span></td><td valign="top" width="14.2857%"><span class="given-date">14</span></td><td valign="top" width="14.2857%"><span class="given-date">15</span></td><td valign="top" width="14.2857%"><span class="given-date">16</span></td><td valign="top" width="14.2857%"><div class="current-day"><span class="given-date">17</span></div></td><td valign="top" width="14.2857%" class="week-day"><span class="given-date">18</span></td><td valign="top" width="14.2857%" class="week-day"><span class="given-date">19</span></td></tr><tr><td valign="top" width="14.2857%"><span class="given-date">20</span></td><td valign="top" width="14.2857%"><span class="given-date">21</span></td><td valign="top" width="14.2857%"><span class="given-date">22</span></td><td valign="top" width="14.2857%"><span class="given-date">23</span></td><td valign="top" width="14.2857%"><span class="given-date">24</span></td><td valign="top" width="14.2857%" class="week-day"><span class="given-date">25</span></td><td valign="top" width="14.2857%" class="week-day"><span class="given-date">26</span></td></tr><tr><td valign="top" width="14.2857%"><span class="given-date">27</span></td><td valign="top" width="14.2857%"><span class="given-date">28</span></td><td valign="top" width="14.2857%"><span class="given-date">29</span></td><td valign="top" width="14.2857%"><span class="given-date">30</span></td><td valign="top" width="14.2857%" class="disabled">1</td><td valign="top" width="14.2857%" class="disabled" class="week-day">2</td><td valign="top" width="14.2857%" class="disabled" class="week-day">3</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: So basically if I would have saved the first day of the month I could have saved it easily?

Comment: Pretty much, yes, then use the relative date format with the `$d` offset by -1

Comment: @P.Samuel btw, I really like this. I needed to make something like it for a while, but have been putting it off - so thanks for the code :)

Comment: This would not be completed without your help so I should thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is code using the DateTime class, which makes it quite readable:

```
$today = new DateTime('today'); // only change this line to test other months
$this_month = $today->format('M');
$date = clone $today;
$date->modify('first day of this month')->modify('+1 day')->modify('last Monday'); 
do {
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($weekday = 0; $weekday < 7; $weekday++){
       $out = str_replace($this_month, '', $date->format('M'));
       $content = "<span class='given-date'>$out {$date->format('d')}</span>";
       if ($today == $date) $content = "<div class='current-day'>$content</div>";
       $class = ($out ? 'disabled ' : '') . ($weekday > 4 ? 'week-day' : '');
       echo "<td valign='top' width='14.2857%' class='$class'>$content</td>";
       $date->modify('+1 day');
    }
    echo '</tr>';
} while ($date->format('M') == $this_month);
```

Comment: Yeah but this does not include the three letters of the month for next and previous month.

Comment: Added that 3-letter month prefix. But note that the accepted answer also does not include those. That answer does also not display the days in 2 digits. I also wonder if you would not want to apply the weekend class to weekend days that are outside the current month? I have done that now, as it seemed more logical to me.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is quite old now I found [Jeff's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4233593/jeff-puckett) solution very useful. I refactored it a little and put it in this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/localgrr/11db2220be7400f62b30a0a98ee02e9b), I hope someone finds it useful. Part of it is here:

```php
/**
 * Return part of an HTML table containing all the days 
 * in the current month, plus padd it with next and 
 * previous months days if needed to fill out the grid
 *
 *
 * @param date $date date object containing month to display
 * 
 * @return string
 */
function get_calendar_days_in_month_html($date) {

    $date_format = "Y-m-d"; 
    
    $days_count = $date->format('t'); //Get number of days in this month
    
    $weeks_count = ceil($days_count / 7); //How many weeks in this month?

    $total_cells = $weeks_count * 7; 
    
    //clone is used or we literally are modifying the $date variable
    $first_date_of_month = clone $date->modify('first day of this month');

    $first_day_of_month = $first_date_of_month->format("N"); //returns 1-7 EG Mon-Fri

    $first_date_of_grid = $first_date_of_month ->modify('-' . $first_day_of_month . ' days');

    $todays_date = new DateTime();

    $todays_date_str = $todays_date->format($date_format);

    $selected_date_str = $date->format($date_format);

    $day_of_week = 1; //FIXME: allow starting with Sunday or whatever

    $ht = '<tr>';

    for ($cell=1; $cell <= $total_cells ; $cell++) { 

        $classes = []; //CSS classes

        $current_date = $first_date_of_grid->modify("+1 day");

        $current_date_str = $current_date->format($date_format);

        if($current_date_str == $todays_date_str) $classes[] = "today";

        if($selected_date_str == $todays_date_str) $classes[] = "selected-date";

        /* if current date is not from this month (EG previous or next month) then give 
        it a special class, you might want to grey it out or whatever */
        if($date->format("m") !== $current_date->format("m")) $classes[] = "grid-filler";

        $ht .= '
        <td date="' . $current_date_str . '" class="' . implode(" ", $classes) . '">' . $current_date->format("j") . '</td>';

        $day_of_week ++;

        if($day_of_week == 8) {

            $ht .= '</tr>';
            if($cell < $total_cells) $ht .= '<tr>';
            $day_of_week = 1;

        }

    }

    return $ht;
}
```